# angular1 es6 service with params

Tags: angularjs, es6-class

My goal is to get a service
with custom params

What's about ?

```
class ApartmentsGridPaginator {
  constructor(pageSize, navRange, data) {}
}
//.service('ApartmentsGridPaginatorFactory', ApartmentsGridPaginatorFactory)
class ApartmentsGridPaginatorFactory {
  getPaginator(pageSize, navRange,data){
    return new ApartmentsGridPaginator(pageSize, navRange, data);
  }
}
class ApartmentsController {
  constructor(ApartmentsGridPaginatorFactory) {
    'ngInject';

    this.paginator = ApartmentsGridPaginatorFactory.getPaginator(30, 5, []);
  }
}
```

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For classes that don't need to use DI `service` shouldn't be used.

Instead, the service may be defined as `value` and contain a constructor:

```
class ApartmentsGridPaginator {
  constructor(pageSize, navRange, data) {}
}

app.value('ApartmentsGridPaginator', ApartmentsGridPaginator);

...

class ApartmentsController {
  constructor(ApartmentsGridPaginator) {
    'ngInject';

    this.paginator = new ApartmentsGridPaginator(30, 5, []);
  }
}
```

Notice that the service follows established naming convention, injected item is a constructor and has PascalCase name.